# Copy Cell's Formula result as Value into same Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code I have written to find values over 0 in a particular column:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To a
        If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value > 0 Then
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Copy
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

My problem is in the copy and paste value.  I need to just copy the cell and paste value in that same cell.  for example, if the macro reads in cell c5 that the total is greater then 0, then it copies cell c5 and paste value in c5.

How do I fix the paste value line to paste the value in the same cell it copied?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using copy/paste, just do it like this:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a with block to limit the amount of repetitive typing

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 To a
        With .Cells(i, 3)
            If .Value > 0 Then .Value = .Value
        End With
    Next
End With
End Sub
```